# Read n rows from x row in sas datasets in python

Tags: pandas, sas

Is there any way to read n rows from row say 25 of sas dataset in python. Can we provide range in chunksize?

Answer (score 4):

we can do a hack with `chunksize`:

```
a = pd.read_sas('file.sas7bdat', chunksize=11)
df = a.read()
a.close()

print(df)
```

Comment: What if we dont want top n rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pyreadstat`](https://ofajardo.github.io/pyreadstat_documentation/_build/html/index.html), the main advantage over `pandas.read_sas` is that `pyreadstat` allows to read data starting from any rows up to any rows i.e. from n rows to m rows. `pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat` has two parameters: `row_offset` and `row_limit`, the reading will start from the `row_offset+1` and number of rows read will be the `row_limit`

```py
import pyreadstat
df, _ = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat('file.sas7bdat', row_offset=10, row_limit=8)

#row_offset=10 means it will start reading from 11th row
#row_limit=8 means it will read next 8 rows from row_offset+1
```

Comment: By 'start after 10th row' does that mean that offset=10 means you start reading from the 11th row instead of starting from the 10th row?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think language was a bit confusing, It's clear now I guess @Tom

Comment: Thanks.  I suspect that python is one of those computer languages that skipped learning how to count in kindergarten and so numbers from zero instead of one.

Answer (score -1):

```py
 import pandas as pd
 a = pd.read_sas('file.sas7bdat')
 df = a.loc[10:25]
 print(df)
```

10 - start; 25 stop.